# How to keep original comments when destructing

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, comments

Using VSCode I want to expand Math object in `Typescript`, and give some tips via comments, but there are some problems.

For example, If you hover on `Math.log()`, you will get:

[image: Comment of Math.log]

But if you destructure it and hover, you will get:

[image: Comment after destruction]

It just shows the type but the comments are gone.

Using `const log = Math.log` will get the same.

Comment: Are you making a new Math constant that uses some existing functions from the built-in Math module plus some of your own?

Comment: No, I want to export those functions directly without a default export. But I do use exisiting functions from vanilla JavaScript `Math`.

Comment: The challenge here is that doc comments are bound to the variable or declaration that immediately follows. You're essentially assigning the existing `Math.log` value to your own new `log` variable which means the doc comments won't carry over. I stumbled across this [@inheritDoc comment tag](https://tsdoc.org/pages/tags/inheritdoc/) that may help, but from my tinkering it looks like VSCode Intellisense doesn't recognize it. What I did notice, however, was that the doc comments still showed up when calling the function (when you type the opening set of parens), just not on hover.

Comment: I tried @inheritDoc, but it didn't work. And you're right, when calling functions, the comments back. But I'm building a library, after build, no comment is left. So I'm considering to add comment to every function.